# Enable debug log for Self Service Portal user action

Tags: customer-portal, debugging

Use case:

- SelfService Portal (yes, an old org ca. 2007 but still using this feature)
- Triggers and workflows associated with `CaseComment`
- Case comment added from Self Service Portal as in screen shot below

**Question:** If the triggers/workflows aren't doing what one expects, how does one debug this using the Debug Log?

Facts as I see them:

- The running user is not the automated case user when case comments are inserted
- The running user is of type `SelfServiceUser` (key prefix 035)
- Trace Flags can't be set for `SelfServiceUser`, only `User`

Short of injecting a beacon into the org that uses an email alert or apex outbound email to broadcast fields that might be of use in diagnostics, is there some other alternative that exploits the OOTB debug log?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried turning on class specific debugs in the developer console?  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_debugging_debug_log.htm You'll have to keep the dev console open while running your tests but it should work. If you want to debug issues when you're logged in as a certain user you might consider using test classes with system.runAs

Comment: @Toby - 1) class-specific and trigger-specific trace flags override the default log levels for the running user; 2) `SelfServiceUser`s aren't `User`s so you can't do `system.runAs()` and 3) I'm not running tests, I'm diagnosing a live system from a user event on the Self Service portal

Comment: I understand you're not running tests but code is code. all you have to do is trigger the code to get a debug log. 1) Doesn't sound like an issue?

Comment: @Toby -- maybe I'm missing something but debug logs are associated with users and enabled when you setup logging for that user. For a self-service portal user, there is no user to enable the log for as SSP users aren't users.

Comment: Look at the link I provided, you can set it up to run for a specific class in the developer console. Than you can do what ever you want in SF as long as you leave the dev console open and it will track any logs related to that class.

Comment: @Toby - well, I learned something :-)  However, my current issue is debugging a workflow from the live SSP site :-(

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how well it will translate to your use case but I just tested a class specific debug log and I was able to get it to include the workflow rules without doing anything crazy. It seems the class specific logs `might` include the entire apex context and not just the one class.

Comment: i will give this a whirl; there is a trigger on `CaseComment` so if I do what you suggest, I might be able to get the WF debug trace as well.

Comment: @Toby -- I may be dense but per the link you suggested, `Setting class and trigger trace flags doesn’t cause logs to be generated or saved. Class and trigger trace flags override other logging levels, including logging levels set by user trace flags, but they don’t cause logging to occur.`  That is, simply setting a trace flag on a trigger doesn't cause logging to occur for any user executing that trigger, debug logs occur if the running user has an active trace flag. The class/trigger trace flags override the logging level for that class/trigger compared to the user's logging level

Comment: Hmm you may be right. It may just be coincidental that it has always done what I needed it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's the answer from SFDC R&D via Premier Support

> As they prioritize the work that most strongly benefits the greatest
>   number of customers, and while this particular feature would be nice
>   to have, we don't feel it's ever going to reach the top of the list.
>   Please feel free to enter this as an IdeaExchange idea and gather
>   support for it; if enough customers feel this would be highly valuable
>   to them we can reassess the priority.

I am not surprised - Self Service Portal is an obsolescent feature.

The only workaround is to install beacons in your triggers, workflows or process builder logic. Such beacons would either send emails or write to a persistent object (such as the Case) with details known to the trigger/workflow/process and hope that yields enough insight as to why your trigger/workflow/or process is not behaving as you would expect.